# Laptop Fn key code for bindsym in i3wm

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, i3-wm, remapping, keycodes

I am using i3wm with ubuntu 20.04. I would like to Fn+Left/Right work as End/Home like in my previous laptop. I know how to make bindsyn in i3wm config but I cannot find Fn code. I used xev but it show nothing after click Fn button. On my laptop Fn+Left/Right do nothing more than single Left/Right.

I am using lenovo legion for now.

I will be very happy if you will give me any idea how to get this key code or how to resolve my problem some other ways.

Thanks in advance,
Simon

@Edit

As long as it not possible I think that maybe Alt+Left/Right would be good for me. I look in internet and found out that this should work well

```
bindsym --release mod1+Right exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers End
```

I thought that Shift+Alt+Right will select from curson till end of line while it select at end of file :D

Can I kindly ask to explain why it's like that and how maybe I could resolve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you experience yourself, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key of your laptop is not recognized by the operating system. It is a key that modifies the behaviour of other keys on the keyboard as defined by the manufacturer. You cannot access or redefine the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in software.

Comment: I was worrying that it work like that.. Thanks, I hope that it won't be wrong if I will sth more about it, I edited my Q - thanks!

Comment: `xbindkeys` recognizes it in sway. I doubt that is true.

Comment: @lsd For me, at least, it is true.